# cargar un Dropdown según valor de otro JQuery/Html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

no conozco básicamente nada de JQuery, pero lo usé con éxito para cargar los valores de un dropdown dependiendo del valor seleccionado en otro (Distrito, Calle). El caso es que estaba funcionando divinamente hasta que hice un cambio en la estructura de mi html, y ahora no funciona. No pensé que el cambio afectaría esto, y no logro entender porqué lo afectó y mucho menos cómo arreglarlo. Agradecería cualquier orientación al respecto.

La función Jquery que uso es la siguiente:

```
<script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#district").change(function () {
 
          $('#street').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');
          
         $("#district option:selected").each(function () {
            id_district = $(this).val();
            $.post("getStreet.php", { id_district: id_district }, function(data){
              $("#street").html(data);
            });            
          });
        })
      });
    </script>
```

Básicamente, según entiendo, eso captura el evento de cambio de mi campo District, y usando mi función getstreet carga los datos en mi campo Street.

El cambio que hice se debe a que dependiendo de otro campo yo quiero que se vea o no estos campos, entonces lo que hice fue agregarle un id a la fila en la tabla (tr) y ponerle display none.

```
              echo '<tr id="SR1" style="display:none"> ';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteFieldCaptionTD">District</td>';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteFieldCaptionTD">';
              echo '<select class="BlueNoteSelect" id="district" name="district" style="WIDTH: 170px; HEIGHT: 20px">';
              echo '<option value="" selected>Select Value</option>';
              $Dist = new District($DB);
              $ListDist = $Dist->GetData($DB, 0);
              $CountList = Count($ListDist['records']);
              for ($i=0; $i<=$CountList-1; $i++) {
                echo '<option value="'.$ListDist["records"][$i]['dist_id'].'" ';
                echo '>'.$ListDist["records"][$i]['descr'].'</option>';
              }
              echo '</select></td>';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteFieldCaptionTD">Erf no</td>';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteDataTD"><input class="BlueNoteInput" maxlength="20" value="" name="erf_no2" id="erf_no2"></td>';
              echo '<input type="hidden" value="" name="unit_no" id="unit_no">'; 
              echo '</tr>';

              
              echo '<tr  id="SR2"  style="display:none"> ';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteFieldCaptionTD">Street Name&nbsp;</td> ';
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteDataTD"><select style="WIDTH: 170px; HEIGHT: 20px" name="street" id="street" >';
                    
              echo '</select></td>'; 
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteFieldCaptionTD">Street No&nbsp;</td>'; 
              echo '<td class="BlueNoteDataTD"><input class="BlueNoteInput" maxlength="10" size="10"  name="streetno" id="streetno" value=""></td></tr>';
```

finalmente tengo una función que según el valor de otro campo cambia el valor del display de estas líneas:

```
function SetUnitType(f){

    var STC = document.getElementById("SecTitleComplex");
    var SRC1 = document.getElementById("SRComplex1");
    var SRC2 = document.getElementById("SRComplex2");
    var SR1 = document.getElementById("SR1");
    var SR2 = document.getElementById("SR2");
    if (document.getElementById("sect_residential").checked){
        STC.style.display = "table-row"; 
        SRC1.style.display = "none";
        SRC2.style.display = "none";
        SR1.style.display = "none";
        SR2.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("single_residential").checked) {
       if (document.getElementById("complex_id_new").value == "")
       {          
          STC.style.display = "none"; 
          SRC1.style.display = "none";
          SRC2.style.display = "none";
          SR1.style.display = "table-row";
          SR2.style.display = "table-row";
       } else {
          STC.style.display = "none"; 
          SRC1.style.display = "table-row";
          SRC2.style.display = "table-row";
          SR1.style.display = "none";
          SR2.style.display = "none";
       }
    } 
    else {
      alert("Please select Sectional Title or Single Residential");
    }
  }
```

cabe destacar que las filas en las que se encuentran estos campos se despliegan o no en los mismos casos. El tema es que al hacer estos cambios la carga de Street dejó de funcionar, y yo sospecho que es debido al nombre en la fila, pero no estoy segura y no he podido corregirlo.